# MySQL 5.7 using /tmp directory, and filling it up

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

We have recently upgraded from MySQL 5.5 to 5.7.26.

When running the following query:

```
INSERT INTO table1_archive 
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE dc between "2019-06-01 00:10:00" and "2019-06-31 23:59:59";
```

It is now filling up the `/` directory, and then failing. This was not the case in MySQL 5.5, where the same query has been running for years.

If I run `explain` on the query there is no mention of `using temporary`, so I can't see why it is suddenly using up all the `/` space.

Looking at the docs the only thing I can see is that

> When selecting from and inserting into the same table, MySQL creates
>   an internal temporary table to hold the rows from the SELECT

but I am using two different tables, so this shouldn't be the case.

Is there something else in MySQL 5.7 causing `INSERT . . SELECT. .` queries to use `/`, and is there something I can do (other than create a huge `/` directory just for these occasional queries)

---

the `tmpdir` is currently set to `/tmp` which is 9GB (compared to the data directory at 1.5 TB, and mounted on `/var/lib/mysql`). And the buffer pool is 100GB.

The table is:

`CREATE TABLE`table1_archive`(`
MId`int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`
FId`int(11) DEFAULT NULL,`
JId`int(11) DEFAULT NULL,`
Head`varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,`
MStat`tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,`
Latest`tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',`
Deleted`tinyint(2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,`
CBy`int(11) DEFAULT NULL,`
Rec`int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,`
Rec2`varchar(65) DEFAULT NULL,`
dc`datetime DEFAULT NULL,`
proc`datetime DEFAULT NULL,`
SReq`datetime DEFAULT NULL,`
Del`datetime DEFAULT NULL,`
RAt`datetime DEFAULT NULL,`
WRAt`datetime DEFAULT NULL,`
WDelAt`datetime DEFAULT NULL,`
Del`datetime DEFAULT NULL,`
Text`blob,`
Num`int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,`
TB1`longblob,`
TB2`longblob,`
TB3`longblob,
  . . .`
TB128`longblob,`
Error`int(11) DEFAULT NULL,`
FName`varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,`
BF`longblob,`
NAtt`tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,`
EStat`tinyint(2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,`
Erron`varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,`
EError`varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,`
Hold`tinyint(2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`MId`),
  KEY`FId`(`FId`),
  KEY`MStat`(`MStat`),
  KEY`CBy`(`CBy`),
  KEY`Rec`(`Rec`),
  KEY`dc`(`dc`),
  KEY`Deleted`(`Deleted`),
  KEY`Error`(`Error`),
  KEY`JId`(`JId`),
  KEY`EStat`(`EStat`),
  KEY`Del`(`Del`),
  KEY`Hold`(`Hold`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`

n.b. I left out a load of TBn fields in the middle, as they are all identical.

The explain is:

`{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "11005387.01"
    },
    "table": {
      "insert": true,
      "table_name": "table1_archive",
      "access_type": "ALL"
    },
    "insert_from": {
      "table": {
        "table_name": "table1",
        "access_type": "range",
        "possible_keys": [
          "Created"
        ],
        "key": "Created",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "Created"
        ],
        "key_length": "6",
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 7860990,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 7860990,
        "filtered": "100.00",
        "index_condition": "(`db1`.`table1`.`dc`between '2019-06-01 00:10:00' and '2019-06-31 23:59:59')",
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "9433189.01",
          "eval_cost": "1572198.00",
          "prefix_cost": "11005387.01",
          "data_read_per_join": "17G"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "MId",
          "FId",
          "JId",
          "Head",
          "MStat",
          "Latest",
          "Deleted",
          "CBy",
          "Rec",
          "Rec2",
          "dc",
          "Proc",
          "SReq",
          "Del",
          "RAt",
          "WRAt",
          "WDelAt",
          "Del",
          "Text",
          "Num",
          "TB1",
          "TB2",
          "TB3",
          . . .
          "TB128",
          "Error",
          "FName",
          "BF",
          "NAtt",
          "EStat",
          "Erron",
          "EError",
          "Hold"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Is your `table1.dc` field indexed (single field or as a prefix)?

Comment: Sorry, yes it is. The field is `dc datetime DEFAULT NULL`. . . `KEY dc ('dc'),`

Comment: Then _that_ query should not be using a temp table.  Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON INSERT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE table1`.

Comment: Are there any triggers on the target table?

Comment: Nope, no triggers, partitions, foreign keys etc.